# What happens when a human saves another one with a death note?

Tags: death-note

Since a shinigami dies when he saves a human with his death note, he dies. But when a human does it, he/she won't die. This makes me wondering what happens when a human saves another human with a death note. So here's my bad example:

Mr. X is a serial killer.

He sees a young Lady and decides to kill her. He stalks her, to know her better.

One week later, the boyfriend from the lady gets a death note from a shinigami.

On the next day, Mr. X tries to kill the lady but her boyfriend writes Mr. Xs name in his death note. Will the young Lady now get a new lifespan. Or will she get the lifespan from Mr. X?

(Just an example)

Comment: I believe she will get the lifespan Mr.X gave her

Comment: Nothing happens, humans did that all through the show.  Light, Miza, Mikami all used it for someone else at one point or another. Remember hostage/robbery in episode 1 or 2?

Comment: @Quikstryke if your talking about Kuro Otoharada's (a criminal who has held a group of children hostage), that was in [Episode 1: Rebirth](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rebirth)

Comment: "Or will she get the lifespan from Mr. X?" According to the manga transfering liefetime only works in two ways: 1) Shinigami writes the name of a human to steal his/ her lieftime. 2) Shinigami uses the death note to extend a dear human's life, dies and it's lifetime goes to the safed human (that is what Rem sais but it is likely that it is just a new lifestime beacause Misa had have a huge lifespan after two Shinigamis gave their lifes for her and so she could become some 100 years old even after 2 eye deals)

Answer (score 4):

How to use LIX:

> A human death caused by Death Note will indirectly lengthen some other human's original life even without a specific intention to lengthen a particular person's original life span in the human world.

The lady's life will be lengthened to a new time

Comment: Since the Death Note rules seem to be confusing to a lot of people, I want to point out that this is the correct answer.

Comment: Though we get an explanation by one of the shinigami in the show. I believe it was Rem who explicitly states that only the fact that shinigami exist to shorten humans lifetimes makes them die from saving them and adding their own lifespan to the saved human ones.

Comment: At another occasion (related to the eyeball deal), we learn that every time a name is written in a Death Note, the natural life spans of some human will change but humans with shinigami eyes don't see the "updates". So if the boyfriend had the eyeballs, saw that his girlfriend's life would end that day and killed the stalker with the note to save her, even when she was really going to die in an accident, her life span would change since she propably wouldn't taking the same rout at the same time since her stalker died right infront of her.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with [Grimlock77X comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15042/what-happens-when-a-human-saves-another-one-with-a-death-note#comment19646_15042). It's stated in the rules and by Ryuk that the fundamental difference between Humans and Shinigami using the Death Note is that humans don't gain lifespans.

[In How to Use: XLII](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_XLII)

> The use of the Death Note in the human world sometimes affects other humans' lives *or* shortens their original life span, even though their names are not actually written in the Death Note itself. In these cases, no matter the cause, the god of death sees only the original lifespan and not the shortened lifespan.

^ emphasis added by me

since the rule says it that the use of the Death Note can affect lives *or* shorten the original life span we can assume that the Death Note can indirectly give a human more life.

think about rape victims who are denied justice (like [Yonegoro Nusumi's](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Yonegoro_Nusumi) victim), if cop drama's like Law and Oder: SVU is anything to go by, without counseling their life deteriorates. with Light killed Yonegoro Nusumi or anyone like him the victims feel justice have been served and improve their lives (and there are no future victims for serial offenders) or wont commit suicide from the denied justice.

As for the lifespans, according to [this answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/15079/1587) Mr X's lifespan would be just wasted so this isn't distributed. there is also no way guarantee the lady would've lived longer or even shorter because of his death, I dare say also that even with Shinigami Eyes you won't see if the lady lives longer since Shinigami will only ever see the original lifespan so likewise a human with the eye deal will see the same, the only way is if you were like Beyond Birthday or L and had worked out how to read Lifespans and knew when the lady would die

Comment: yeah but how can the lifespan increase? Does the saved person get a new lifespan?

Comment: @DarkYagami not entirely sure, since the rule says it can affect others lives, as per my answer i assume they do gain new death dates but exactly where the added lifespan comes from i don't know. it may have something to do with [this question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/15077/1587) i suspect

Comment: @DarkYagami: Yes. Whenever the Death Note is used, it alters the future, and everyone who it affects has their lifespan recalculated.

Comment: This rule always confused me. Supposedly the god of death would always see the original lifespan, regardless whether it had been lengthened. But Misa's lifespan was lengthened when the death god sacrificed himself for her, yet Rem still says to Light "If Misa dies before her time runs out, I will hold you responsible". Now how would she be able to see this? Misa's lifespan should have ended a long time ago already according to quoted rule, yet Rem could see the new lifespan?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I think the difference is because the death note then was used in the Shinigami Realm since the rule says "*the use of the death note in the human world*". So either the use of death note in the Shinigami Realm allows Shinigami to see updated lifespans or when humans use the death note Shinigami don't see the updates (since what's the likelihood of a human using the death note in the Shinigami realm)