# What happens to the lifespan not collected by Shinigami?

Tags: death-note

In the [Rules of the Death Note](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note) (i can't remember exactly which rule) and said by Ryuk himself when he was explaining things to Light ealry in the series, the main difference between a Human using the Death Note and a Shinigami using the Death Note is that Humans don't gain the difference in lifespan when they take a life while Shinigami do.

Now considering all the people the Kiras took the life of, they all could have been potential targets for Shinigami to increase their life.

So i am wondering, what exactly happens to the lifespan that normally would collected by a Shinigami when a Human uses the Death Note?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually covered by the [Rules of the Death Note](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note):

> **How to Use: LIX**
>
> A human death caused by Death Note will indirectly lengthen some other
>   human's original life even without a specific intention to lengthen a
>   particular person's original life span in the human world.

It is likely that this simply means that the person killed "prematurely" has extended other people's lives as they go about their lives differently than if the person was there, thus events leading to their deaths may change.

No other rules of the Death Note cover what you are looking for. Glancing at a few likely places in the manga and reading over the wiki, I cannot find anything specifically stating if anything happens.

Due to Misa's death shortly after the series, we can assume that she gained no extra life span from her efforts. Even when she reduced her life span to a quarter by trading for the shinigami eyes twice, she should have still lived a long time if killing someone influenced her life since it would have been added afterwards.

Additionally, we know that the shinigami owner of the death note does not gain the life span because they did not write the name themselves.

Based on this, I would say that the left-over time is wasted. Other people's lives will be influenced due to the rule above, but the "remaining" time is not distributed in any means.

Comment: but that rule would apply regardless who uses the Death Note, i am asking about when the person who is killed which, if it was done by Shinigami, would normally have their lifespan difference collected and added to the Shinigami's life. since a human using the death note can't collect what happens to it? or do Shinigami not actually get all of the lifespan difference because some is distributed around

Comment: @Memor-X I scanned over my copies of the manga and did some extra research, please see my edits.